# Could minor-third be used to judge major or minor key?

Tags: chords, key

As my background is engineering, I often notice the occurrence of repeated things. I am learning to play pop songs by ear. It seems if a pop song has more minor-third intervals at or around the beginning (or even the whole song?), it has a high chance to be a "minor" song. Am I right?

Note: After some helpful answers/comments below, I actually rethink what and why I ask this question: [1] minor-third in the melody, not chord [2] since the pop song melody movement may start from tonic or end in tonic, there will be a bit higher chance to have m3 there if the melody is minor key. I think this is the reason behind my question.

Comment: I think the OP is talking about m3 that appear in the melody, not chords

Comment: Yes, m3 in the melody as I need to figure out the melody's key  by ear first before I play.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a bit of a flaw to your thinking. Minor and major triads each contain a major 3rd and a minor 3rd. A major triad is M3-m3 and a minor triad is m3-M3. The only time there is a likelihood of a song being in minor if there are m3 intervals in it is if those intervals occur between the tonic and the 3rd degree of whatever the key is. Even this is not foolproof as songs that have a bluesy style often use m3 intervals from the root in the melody even if the song is in a major key. The best way to tell if a song is in a minor key or not is by analyzing the entire melody and harmony, not looking for specific intervals.

Comment: if the song (I mean the melody) starts with descending m3 at the beginning or  descending m3 before the first M3? because the mood of the song actually sounds sad

Comment: @SBMVNO That is a very general and not necessarily accurate statement. You can have a G-E melody (descending m3) over a C major chord and it will not sound sad. Also, a song may start on a minor chord but end up being in a major key. There are too many variables to assume what you’re assuming.

Comment: I think I need to listen more and give more specific statement. Thanks,

Comment: @SBMVNO It is possible that songs that use m3 intervals in the way you’re thinking can be in minor keys but a m3 interval in a melody alone is not enough to define a key.

Comment: @SBMVNO Also in the future even if you like an answer I suggest you not accept answers so quickly, it might discourage others from answering. Give others a chance to answer and offer their insights to your questions.

Comment: @SBMVNO - The Sesame Street theme (last I heard of it) starts with a descending minor 3rd but is actually in a major key. So does the Peppa Pig theme.

Comment: I try to make my question clear. [1] minor-third in the melody, not chord. [2]Since the melody movement may start from tonic or end in tonic, there will be a bit high chance to have m3 there. I think this is the reason behind my question.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Thank you very much for your example. I should write my question better next time. I think It is about the probability.

Comment: @SBMVNO My answer states that when there is a m3 in a melody from the tonic there IS a chance that the song might be in minor but it is not definite. Take the song “Steamroller Blues” it is a major blues and the first 3 notes are m3-m3. If the song is in C the first notes are A-C-Eb-C-A-C-C with the lyrics: I’m a steam-roller ba-by. The m3 interval is not reliable for determining major or minor.

Answer (score 6):

m3 is not a good criterion for defining if a song is in a major or minor key. There are loads of intervals used regularly in all songs, pop or otherwise, and none of them can or do herald that. Especially, as John says, you're dealing with Blues, which are generally in major keys, but use m3 between ^1 and ^3.

Looking at the music is a pretty safe bet for determining a key, but you want to do it by ear.

The way to go - and an engineering, logical background won't be a great help, is to establish the *chords* that are played, rather than the melody. Establish chord I, and that's the safest way. But how to to that?

Listen carefully, and the places where the song feels 'at rest', often at the end, or end of a verse, sometimes the beginning of a verse, will be the most used. Also, try to ascertain the one (I!) chord that keeps recurring. Those are the best clues as to what key a song is in - and whether it's major or minor.

The more you do, the more you listen, the easier it becomes. And playing along with each song (what instrument?) helps a lot. You'll soon realise that I, IV and V are the mainstay of a lot, if not most pop songs, and you'll learn how those chords relate to each other.

For example, if there's some Cs and Gs in a song, it could be in key C *or* key G. Finding the missing chord will help define. If that's F, chances are the key's C, if it's D, chances move to key G. Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

As an engineer would you build a bridge by guesswork?

As a musician understand musical concepts through musical knowledge not guesswork.

To understand *key* at a basic level you must at least:

- learn the concept of tonic
- learn the structure of the diatonic scales major and minor
- learn the basic cadences
- learn the concept of transposition
- learn the key signatures

A song that is truly in a minor key will have a minor third above the tonic and a leading tone one half step below the tonic. That is a super simplified description of the essential scale tones. To explain more is essentially a complete explanation of the first two bullet point above for minor keys.

> ...It seems if a pop song has more minor-third intervals at or around the beginning (or even the whole song?), it has a high chance to be a "minor" song. Am I right? (PS: minor-third in the melody, not chord)

There are two gotchas to be aware for pop songs.

- pop songs are often pentatonic in the melody, which means they don't have a leading tone, and instead the melodies often go *down* a minor third from the tonic to the *submediant*.
- pop songs often have non-diatonic bluesy intervals which can outline a minor third.

Both of those things can happen in a pop song which has a basic major tonality.

The total count of musical elements is normally *not* an important factor in analyzing tonal music. The *relative* relationship of pitches is much, much more important.